# Trying to create a DvbBufferedImage but its width and height are 0

Tags: java-me, xlet, blu-ray

I'm trying to create a fade-in animation using DvbBufferedImage for my BD-J application by changing alpha value of the images,

```
doubleBuffer = new DVBBufferedImage(1920, 2180, DVBBufferedImage.TYPE_ADVANCED);
```

but after it creates the buffer, its width and height are 0 and when I'm trying to get graphics:

```
DVBGraphics bufferGraphics = doubleBuffer.createGraphics();
```

It returns null.

after that, I want to draw images onto buffer and I get `NullPointerException`.
Do you have and suggestion?
I think it is related to my libraries, because when I replaced `DvbBufferedImage` with  `BufferedImage` using this code:

```
protected BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(1920, 2180, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
```

it says :

> The constructor BufferedImage(int, int, int) is undefined

I mention that I'm using customized eclipse for developing Bd-j Applications and my java version is `jre1.8.0_77`.

Classes used for this application listed below:

```
basis.jar
btclasses.zip
j2me_xml_cdc.jar
javatv.jar
jsse-cdc.jar
pbp_1_0.jar
SonicBDJ.jar
```

Your help will be appreciated on this problem, Thanks in advance!

Comment: `1920x2180`? What kind of resolution is that?

Comment: I want to use this 1920x2180 image as my map, load it onto a buffer (dvbbufferedimage of bufferedimage) then draw some part of it to this buffer and generate my final image. then I use this image for running animation (by changing its alpha value)

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a memory issue.

Blu-ray Players are only required to have 4 mb of memory according to the specification. This includes the space for the actual JAR file currently loaded. So if you're using an image of 1920x2180 pixels in high quality, then your JAR is probably already taking up 1-2 mb. Then loading that image into memory might cause an `OutOfMemoryException`, which means the image won't be loaded, which is why you get the `NullPointerException`.

Blu-ray Disc Java is JavaME. We're dealing with a limited platform. ;-)